# Rake aborting on Rails app Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rake, passenger

Getting the following error when running $rake:

```
$ rake
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- redcarpet.so
/var/www/my_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redcarpet-3.2.3/lib/redcarpet.rb:1:in `require'
/var/www/my_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redcarpet-3.2.3/lib/redcarpet.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/my_app/code/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/my_app/code/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Ruby -v : 2.2.3
rbenv local/global : 2.2.3

Rails -v : 4.2.4

I also tried reinstalling the redcarpet gem with :

```
sudo gem install redcarpet 
Fetching: redcarpet-3.3.4.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed redcarpet-3.3.4
1 gem installed
```

Which ran fine. Any ideas on what would be causing this to abort?

Comment: I guess you could try to install the gem without the `sudo`. I've had problems with it in the past ;)

Comment: Could it be because your ruby version is 2.2.3 and rake is looking for gems under ruby 2.2.0?

Comment: How would I get that to look in the correct ruby version? @MarceloRisoli

Comment: I had also tried it without the sudo, that hadn't worked either. @RafaelGoulart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a bundle install locally, pushed it up to git again and then did a cap production deploy. That seemed to fix it for some reason. Now to move on to all the database errors that I have.